# Logging into another website that uses WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

Tags: javascript, .net, forms, model-view-controller, webforms

I am making Website (A) using using the .NET MVC 5 Framework and I need to be able to login to Website (B) to download a file / scrape HTML, Website B is built on .NET Webforms. I initially looked into utilizing WebClient / HttpClient to create the login request, but to my dismay Website B's login process uses the Javascript function *WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions*.

Due to this it doesn't pass any of the login values in the request, I could be wrong but I analyzed the requests with fiddler and could not find anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can achieve authenticating into a Website that uses WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions, would I be able to do something like this programmatically or would I need to use a library like ScrapySharp?

Here is some html that Website B uses in it's log in form as reference

```
<input type="text" id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_ctrlLogin_UserName" size="30" maxlength="100" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$ctrlLogin$UserName">

<input type="password" id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_ctrlLogin_Password" size="30" maxlength="50" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$ctrlLogin$Password">

<input type="submit" class="Button130" id="ctl00_PageContent_ctl00_ctrlLogin_LoginButton" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$ctrlLogin$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Group1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" value="Login" name="ctl00$PageContent$ctl00$ctrlLogin$LoginButton">
```